# Get Items Expiring in Next 180 days

Tags: list, list-view, date-time

I am looking to create  a view where users can pull report of expiring licenses 180  days from now. I have [End Date] set as expiring date. How can i create a view where it will pull data expiring 180 days from NOW(GetDate).

Answer (score 1):

In your view settings, use the filter

```
End Date 
is greater than
[Today]-180
```